# Simplified version of LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a function which takes two dates i.e., fromdate and todate and a timezone (UTC and IST).

Based on these I need to filter a list of objects which has a field called "StartDate" to be between FromDate and ToDate.

```
public void CheckDate(ref List<CustomObj> cObj,DateTime fromdate, DateTime toDate,object timeZone)
{

 cObj = cObj.where( x => 
 {

  bool result = false;
  switch(timeZone)
  {
    case "UTC" :
                var utc = Convert.ToDateTime(x.StartDate);
                if(fromDate <= utc && utc <= toDate)
                {
                  result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                  result = false;
                }
                break;
    case "IST" :
              {
               // Similar logic but convert to IST and check
              }
              break;
         }
      }
   }
```

This function works fine but is there any way I can simplify this by writing simplified LINQ query and not write too much of logic in the where clause of lambda for making it look simple?

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't compile - so it's hard to know *exactly* what works and what doesn't. Could you provide a [mcve] example for us to work with, please?

Comment: @jon : the function  filters the list of customobj which the conditions  satisfy .

Comment: as other comments bellow I should prefer use only one way to store my dates in the database. if the dates come with different format then I should use a date extension in order to convert them to you database format

Comment: Just out of curiosity .. have you looked at DateTimeOffset. Which will calculate the conversion for you?

Comment: As I say, the method won't compile at the moment, so I'm not going to look at ways to improve it - especially as some might break desired behaviour that you haven't told us about. A [mcve] would really help this question to go from "hard to answer well" to "an interesting question". You've already got answers, so you may not want to put the time in - but I'd encourage you to do so.

Comment: This would make an interesting interview question. There is the elementary issue of the string passed as an object. The intermediate issue that the OP is asking about. And the "only seasoned developers will notice" issue of the ambiguous definition of the `timeZone` parameter. Does it specify the time zone of the `CustomObj` instances, the timezone of the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters, or the timezones of both? If the answer is both, the logic is identical for both cases and the argument can be ignored. Trick question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only supporting two time zones, a ternary operator may be sufficient. You could check if it's IST, otherwise default to UTC.

```
    public void CheckDate(ref List<CustomObj> cObj, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, string timeZone)
    {
        cObj = cObj.Where(x =>
        {
            var date = timeZone == "IST" ? /*convert to IST*/ : Convert.ToDateTime(x.StartDate);
            return fromDate <= date && date <= toDate;
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you got is not bad. The logic has branches, so you'll have to branch.

We can cut a few things still, and seperate reusable logic:

```cs
public void CheckDate (List<CustomObj> cObj, DateTime fromdate, DateTime toDate, object timeZone) {
    cObj = cObj.where (x => {
        var recordStartDate = ConvertDate (timeZone, x.StartDate);
        return recordStartDate.HasValue && // Your choice whether you want to exclude null
            fromDate <= recordStartDate.Value && recordStartDate.Value <= toDate;
    });
}

public static DateTime? ConvertDate (string timeZone, DateTime sourceDate) {
    switch (timeZone) {
        case "utc":
            return Convert.ToDateTime (sourceDate);
        case "ist":
            return sourceDate; // IST logic here
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a better practice to store all dates in the same format/timezone (store all dates as UTC), which would make your life a bit easier here. However, you wont be able to simplify much seeing you rely on items in the collection as conditions.

A an alternative to @Meligy's answer, instead of LINQ, perhaps you should just use a traditional foreach loop?

```
    public bool CheckDate(List<CustomObj> cObj, DateTime fromdate, DateTime toDate, object timeZone)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime date;

        foreach(CustomObj obj in cObj)
        {
            date = DateTime.MinValue;
            switch (timeZone)
            {
                case "UTC":
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.StartDate);
                    break;
                case "IST":
                    // stuff
                    break;
            }

            if (date >= fromdate && date <= toDate)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this

```html
        public int CheckDate(ref List<dates> cObj, DateTime fromdate, DateTime toDate, string timeZone)
        {
            var currentZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);

            var result = (from obj in cObj
                         let currdTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(obj.StartDate, currentZone)
                         where fromdate <= currdTime && toDate >= currdTime
                         select obj).ToList();

            return result.Count() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
```

You can make use of the inbuilt Timezone class and its standard name and convert the time to your desired timezone and compare. Maybe you can grab and create a custom Enumeration class of all Standard Timezones, so when you include a timezone in future you don't have to make a change in the code. The code is untested, but I hope it gives you an idea on how to achieve your output.